# Can I deploy a Go project in Tomcat?

Tags: go, tomcat, deployment

I have an application written in spring-boot and exposed it as rest API(s) by hosting it in tomcat. I want to rewrite this in Go and deploy it. How to deploy the Go project?

Comment: build the go binary on the OS, run the binary, other than that, you should not need any other runtime.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Your questions about Tomcat and Swagger are completely unrelated. Ask one per post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java web projects using the Servet API require a servlet container to run, such as Tomcat. Further, Java is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language): programs written in Java require the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) to run.

Go on the other hand is a [compiled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language): programs written in Go can be compiled into an executable native binary that can be run directly by the operating system without any additional runtime. (Go also has a runtime but that's much smaller than JRE and is included in each executable binary.)

So web applications written in Go do not require other apps (such as servlet containers) to run. You just compile your Go app and run it like any other apps on your computer.

Comment: In addition to what icza said, you should consider either tightening the security (and timeouts and request rate control and whatnot) in your program if you decide to make it accessible from the Internet directly (and then you might start [there](https://blog.cloudflare.com/exposing-go-on-the-internet/)) or you might consider placing it behind a reverse proxy such as `nginx`, which, in the case of a webapp, might also be use to serve static assets.